# Nginx - running python, bash script

Tags: python, bash, nginx

I have an nginx server with the configuration I want to be able to develop with a new address "hooks.devel.nclab.com" (vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/devel.nclab.com):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/ssl-keys/devel.nclab.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl-keys/devel.nclab.key;
    set $hook_home /home/labdevel/core/static/hooks;
    root $hook_home;
    server_name hooks.devel.nclab.com;

    location ~ (\.py|\.sh)${
        gzip off;
        root $hook_home;
        autoindex on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $hook_home;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $hook_home$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I've created a simple python file to the directory given as $hook_home as "hello.py".

```
print "hello"
```

When I type "https://hooks.devel.nclab.com:443/hello.py" in the browser and give my user and password it says: "404: Not Found".

Where do I mess up the code?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: For starters you have the server block listening on port 8000, but the url youre navigating to does not contain a port number. Furthermore, you're trying to use https, but you don't have any SSL setup, nor are you listening on port 443 required for SSL

Comment: Thanks for the tips, updated the code, but it is still failing... :(

Comment: Is `hello.py` an executable file? And `$hook_home` is somewhat redundant, as there is already a predefined variable called `$document_root` (see [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_document_root)).

Comment: the file is executable, I created the variable, because I was not sure how nginx know in which folder the file is on the server, when i type "domain.com/myfile.py"

Answer (score 0):

**Configuring nginx with the module**

All you need is to change start command to

: static module

```
./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-python-module
```

: dynamic module

```
./configure --add-dynamic-module=/path/to/nginx-python-module
```

: sync-only version

```
./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-python-module 
            --with-cc-op=-DNGX_PYTHON_SYNC=1
```

: the path to python-config prior to configuring

```
export PYTHON_CONFIG=/path/to/python-config
```